# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createElement') at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have 3D cesium globe code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Include the CesiumJS JavaScript and CSS files -->
  <script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.84/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.84/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
  <script>
    // Your access token can be found at: https://cesium.com/ion/tokens.
    // Replace `your_access_token` with your Cesium ion access token.

Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
  imageryProvider: Cesium.createWorldImagery({
    style: Cesium.IonWorldImageryStyle.AERIAL_WITH_LABELS,
  }),
  animation: false,
  timeline: false,
  baseLayerPicker: false,
});

var layers = viewer.scene.imageryLayers;
var blackMarble = layers.addImageryProvider(
  new Cesium.IonImageryProvider({ assetId: 3812 })
);

blackMarble.alpha = 0.5;
blackMarble.brightness = 2.0;
  </script>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

after executing this code i get this error in browser console,

> Cesium.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'createElement')
> at HTMLIFrameElement.

But the globe is being rendered and working but i want to remove this error also from console

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: @emackey, do you know how to fix this? None of the Sandcastle examples address the issue.